# Need to get placeholder text of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Is it possible to get the placeholder value of UITextField, which is designed in storyboard?

I need to validate the form which is having more textfields, so instead of giving static value, I want to give placeholder string of particular textfield as alert message.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `placeholder` property:

```
textField.placeholder
```

Comment: questioner need to retrieve the placeholder Text , can you elaborate your answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The `placeholder` property returns the text. There is no need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

For placeholder first you should create IBOUTLET for textfield and then do:

```
 if let str = textfiled.placeholder {

        if !str.isEmpty {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextField` class has a [`placeholder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/placeholder) property. To reference the `UITextField` in code, you'll need to [create an outlet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) for it in your view controller.

If you named the outlet `myTextField`, you could reference the placeholder like this:

```
let placeholder = self.myTextField.placeholder
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work ...

For getting **placeholder text** you need to wire up your textfield with its IBOutlet object like,

```
@IBOutlet var txtField : UITextField?
```

Now you set Placeholder **Statically** or **dynamically**

```
self.txtField!.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Good", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()])
```

After that anywhere you can simply get its placeholder text and compare or validate ur textfield like

```
if((self.txtField!.placeholder! as NSString).isEqualToString("Good"))
{
    // Do here Whatever you want   
}
else if(self.txtField!.placeholder!.isEmpty == true)
{
   // check its empty or not      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write like below code,

```
if((self.myTextFiled!.placeholder! as NSString).isEqualToString("AnyString"))
{
     // your code here  
}
```